# request.serverVariables() "URL" vs "Script_Name"

Tags: url, asp-classic, request.servervariables

I am maintaining a classic asp application and while going over the code I came across two similar lines of code:

```vb
Request.ServerVariables("URL")
' Output: "/path/to/file.asp"

Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
' Output: "/path/to/file.asp"
```

I don't get it... what is the difference? both of them ignore the URL rewriting that I have set up which puts the /path folder as the root document (the above URL is rewritten to "/to/file.asp")

**More info**:
The site is deployed on IIS 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a bug under IIS 7.

I could not get `Request.ServerVariables("URL")` and `Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")` to return different values. I've tried the cases where they were called from an included file (`<!--#include file="file.asp"-->`) or after a `Server.Transfer`.

Comment: maybe they're just both kept for backwards compatibility?

Comment: @Jim Robert,
I'm not sure to be honest. I've now tried different variations (calling a sub/function that outputs URL and SCRIPT_NAME) but still, they always return the same value. Again, this is tested under IIS 7.

Answer (score 8):

URL Gives the base portion of the URL, without any querystring or extra path information. For the raw URL, use HTTP_URL or UNENCODED_URL.

SCRIPT_NAME A virtual path to the script being executed. Can be used for self-referencing URLs.

See, http://www.requestservervariables.com/url
and /script_name for the definitions.

Comment: That website is one of the least explanatory sites I've ever seen. Looks pretty though.

Answer (score 1):

Is this maybe there in case of Server.Transfer?

In the case where you do a server.transfer i *think* you would get different results

i.e. SCRIPT_NAME would be e.g. /path/to.transferredfile.asp whereas URL would remain as /path/to/file.asp

Comment: No, just tried it. It will both be "/path/to.transferredfile.asp" after Server.Transfer()